# Force photo file to be uploaded from the photo library on a phone

Tags: javascript, html

Clarification: this is for a website, not a web-based app.

I have a file upload button (input type is file) and when the user presses the button, the mobile phone asks whether the user wants to take a new photo, or select an already-made photo.

I want to have two upload buttons, one that is directly linked to the camera and one that is linked to the photo library. I do not want the phone to ask the user what to do, because I want to integrate it into my application's design.

However, I am unable to formulate a short description for my problem and thus Google isn't of much help!

I am looking for some pointers on achieving this, if it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is that the device's default behavior for selecting an image kicks in. You wouldn't be able to bypass this from a website in javascript. (maybe even natively, I'd expect mobile vendors to protect basic functionality like this)

You 'could' depending on what you are building use something like phonegap and a plugin to allow you to trigger an image selection from the devices saved images, but you wouldn't be able to do that from a website as it doesn't have the same level of access to the device.

You can do it the other way and trigger the device's camera with `capture="camera"`, but not the way you want unfortunately.

Comment: It is a website, so any wrapper such as Cordova or Phonegap is out of the question, sadly.